# How do I make this Java return command running?

Tags: java

I am trying to figure out why this return Command is failing.

I did try it with System.out.println(); and it works fine - however I am not able to use this.

Here is my code:

```
class Laufzeit {


double groesster =0;
double zweitgroesster;
double[] x = new double[1000000];


Laufzeit() {};


void fill() {
    for(int i = 0; i< x.length; i++  ) {
        Random random = new Random();
        double a = random.nextDouble();
        x[i] =  a;
    }
}   
double groessterWert() {
    for(int i = 0; i< x.length; i++) {
        if(x[i] > this.groesster) {

            this.groesster = x[i];
        }
    }
    **return this.groesster;**
}

double zweitgroessterWert() {
    for(int i = 0; i< x.length; i++) {
        if(x[i] > groesster) {
            zweitgroesster = groesster;
        }
        else if(x[i] > zweitgroesster){
            zweitgroesster = x[i];
        }

}
    **return zweitgroesster;**

}
}
```

This code is where the highest and second highest number is required.
My code for this seems okay but it is unable to return something.

Here is my main class:

```
class Start {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("time in nanoseconds =");
    long zeit1 = System.nanoTime();


    Laufzeit laufzeit = new Laufzeit();
    laufzeit.fill();
    laufzeit.groessterWert();
    laufzeit.zweitgroessterWert();

    long zeit2 = System.nanoTime();

    long laufzeit1 = zeit2 - zeit1;

    System.out.println(laufzeit1);;
    }

}
```

Any help or guidance will really be appreciated!

Comment: What is your aim here? If you wish to print to the console you must use System.out.println(); or perhaps use a logger

Comment: Well my aim here is, that I want to return the highest number out of the array, but it does not work with return... only with system.out.println()